# Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition on Update

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I get the following error when executing my stored procedure

> Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Procedure dbo.SP_PostYearDataCopy, Line 97 [Batch Start Line 2]
>   Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

My stored procedure looks like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_PostYearDataCopy]
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the variable to be used.
    DECLARE @Year AS INT
    DECLARE @clubYear AS INT

    -- Initialize the variable.
    SET @Year = YEAR(GETDATE()) - 1;
    SET @clubYear = @Year + 1;

    CREATE TABLE #PLAYERTEMP
    (
         PlayerID INT,
         TeamID INT,
         Number INT,
         Year INT
    )

    ---- (STEP 2)
    ---- Create Process for Archiving Team Data and Create next years teams

    CREATE TABLE #TEAMTEMP 
    (
        teamTypeID INT, 
        TeamName VARCHAR(50),
        clubYear VARCHAR(50),
        Age VARCHAR(3), 
        Gender VARCHAR(50),
        Display BIT, 
        CoachID INT,
        CoachAsst INT,
        stateCupID INT,
        Manager VARCHAR(50),
        ManagerID INT,
        LeagueID INT,
        League2ID INT,
        League3ID INT,
        LeagueLink VARCHAR (250),
        LeagueLink2 VARCHAR (250),  
        LeagueLink3 VARCHAR (250),
        Callink VARCHAR (200),
        GotSoccer VARCHAR (250),
        Accomplishments VARCHAR (MAX), 
        Doc varchar(MAX), 
        DocName varchar (200), 
        DocType varchar (5)
    )        

    INSERT INTO #TEAMTEMP
        SELECT 
            teamTypeID, TeamName, clubYear, Age, Gender, Display, 
            CoachID, CoachAsst, stateCupID, Manager, ManagerID, 
            LeagueID, League2ID, League3ID, LeagueLink, LeagueLink2, LeagueLink3, 
            Callink, GotSoccer, Accomplishments, Doc, DocName, DocType
        FROM  
            dbo.Teams
        WHERE 
           (clubYear = @Year) AND (TeamTypeID = 3)

    UPDATE #TEAMTEMP 
    SET clubYear = @clubYear,
        Age = RIGHT(Age, 2) + 1,
        CoachID = NULL,
        CoachAsst = NULL,
        stateCupID = NULL,
        Manager = NULL,
        ManagerID = NULL  <--- LINE 97 --->
```

Comment: the message is very clear. Check your `INSERT` statement

Comment: I did that like 20 times and I don't see anything that is missing.  Do you?

Comment: Yes. the `INSERT` statement looks ok. Try copy the query to a new query window and try. You probably already have a `#TEAMTEMP` already created in the current session (Query Window). You can confirm this by doing a `SELECT * FROM #TEAMTEMP` in the current query window

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I wasn't explicitly setting the fields to insert values into the table. The table had two new fields I forgot were added and the ID field wasn't set to auto increment, so I guess it was also looking for values for that field as well.

After correcting these, the stored procedure ran as expected.

Comment: Good lesson to ALWAYS list column names.